# Apache rewrite with fallback

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

In our AngularJS project I have a set of HTML templates for reports that are currently part of the deployment but this means that whenever our client requests a change to one of the HTML templates I need to make update the complete application.

Is it possible to do the following for a request for these HTML templates:

- Assume the request for `assets/reports/report1.html`.
- Use the file `<external-dir>/assets/reports/report1.html` if that file exists. The external directory is not directly accessible from the internet.
- Otherwise, use the initial request.

Most `mod_rewrite` solutions I could find seem to stop after the first rewrite.

Update: I've added the configuration changes below to the complete virtual host definition but the Alias seems to disrupt things:

```
<iFmODule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    Alias /advisor/report /var/www/html/report
    Alias /report-templates /opt/reports

    #<Directory /var/www/html/report>
      RewriteEngine On

      # Preventing direct access to /report-templates
      RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
      RewriteRule ^/?report-templates(/.*)?$ - [R=404,L]

      # If the request was not already rewritten,
      RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
      # and the file do really exist in /advisor/report/assets/reports
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
      # rewrite the request from /advisor/report/assets/reports to /report-templates
      RewriteRule ^/?advisor/report/assets/reports/(.*)$ /report-templates/$1 [L]

      # If the file do not exist in /report-templates/
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      # rewrite the request back
      RewriteRule ^/?report-templates/(.*)$ /advisor/report/assets/reports/$1 [L]
    #</Directory>

    LogLevel warn rewrite:trace8
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

There are 2 AngularJS applications, the advisor portal located under `/var/www/html/advisor` and the reporting application located under `/var/www/html/report`. The latter is accessed through `https:/example.com/advisor/report` and is the reason for the Alias.

I changed the Alias to:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/advisor>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/?advisor/report/(.*)$ /report/$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

This way the Alias should not interfere. After this I enabled the `<Directory>` directive for `/var/www/html/report` and removed the `advisor/` part from the rewrite rules and conditions but I didn't see the rewrite happening in the logs.

Comment: Thx for the configuration, but now I'm relay confused with your directory structure... what is a real directory what is an alias what is the URl that the browser request?
Which directory is the one the is relevant to us and is there any directory that must be taken care off in one way or another? BTW I do not know how AngularJS applications work, but this is not relevant for rewriting, so please explain it just from the apache point of view. Just which request (URI) should be redirected to what file.... some examples for both applications would help a lot.

Comment: @webdesigner There are two entry points in Apache: `https://advisor.url/` and `https://advisor.url/report`. And two directories under the document root where the individual apps are installed: `advisor` and `report`. The alias is used to map `https://advisor.url/report` calls to the proper document root. What I need to do is serve a file from system directory `/opt/reports/<file>` when it is requested as `https:/advisor.url/report/assets/reports/<file>` unless that file does not exists. In that case I want to serve the original requested file. I hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: But if you have a directories under the document root `/var/www/html` called `/report` and the entry point is `https://advisor.url/report` why you need an Alias?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a directory called `external-dir` in your root (public_html) folder.

If you have full access to your server, this directory could be also somewhere else on the file system, but than you have to add a Alias in your Virtualhost configuration.

```
Alias "/external-dir" "/absolute/path/to/external-dir"
```

and the Apache Module mod_alias must be enabled:

```
sudo a2enmod alias
```

Now the main Part: This procedure will work for all existing files in the folder (or sub folder)  `/assets`. First we check if the same file exist in `/external-dir/assets` and if so we serve it, if not we serve the original one. Its not possible to get a file from `/external-dir/assets` that do not exits in `/assets`. If you need more restrictions you can add them as your need it.

You can put this it in a .htaccess file in your root (public_html) folder or in your Virtualhost configuration, than I would use a [Directory Direktive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) for your root directory

```
RewriteEngine On

# Preventing direct access to /external-dir
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^/?external-dir(/.*)?$ - [R=404,L]

# If the request was not already rewritten,
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
# and the file do really exist in /assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
# rewrite the request from /assets to /external-dir/assets/
RewriteRule ^/?assets/(.*)$ /external-dir/assets/$1 [L]

# If the file do not exist in /external-dir/assets/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# rewrite the request back
RewriteRule ^/?external-dir/assets/(.*)$ /assets/$1 [L]
```

*I tested this positive on an Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS Server with Apache 2.4.27.*

Comment: This looks like it will work! In my own feeble attempts I missed the last part to rewrite the rewrite. The sysadmin who can make this change is not in today but I will let you know if this works.

Comment: Its not only to rewire the rewrite as you call it, the important part is to check it the first rewrite is the initial one, otherwise you end up in an  infinite rewrite loop.

Comment: It doesn't work as I have an Alias that triggers before the rewrite. I've updated the question to include your proposed answer and our exact configuration. @Webdesigner could you take a look at it again?